# S530 Bluetooth earpiece detected as keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo

- Distro & Version Ubuntu 16.04
- Kernal Version 4.4.0-51-generic

When I connect my [S530 Bluetooth Earpiece](http://a.co/534EIX1) it connects as a keyboard and doesn't show up in the sound output settings

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndGuD.png)

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[63536.338157] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[63536.338165] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[63545.087448] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 12
[79979.997536] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[79980.002529] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[79980.002541] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[79980.002547] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[79980.002552] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[79980.002558] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[79980.002565] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[79980.002577] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[79981.356156] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[79981.356507] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1327600 usecs
[79981.356570] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[79981.368553] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11750 usecs
[79981.368566] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[79981.370497] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[79981.371555] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[80783.678378] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[80783.683748] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[80783.683751] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[80783.683753] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[80783.683754] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[80783.683755] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[80783.683757] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[80783.694818] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[80785.093934] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[80785.094321] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1383279 usecs
[80785.094546] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[80785.106384] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11677 usecs
[80785.106486] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[80785.108412] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[80785.109404] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[80813.781243] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[80813.786246] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[80813.786256] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[80813.786261] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[80813.786265] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[80813.786270] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[80813.786275] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[80813.786285] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[80814.926967] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[80816.930951] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[80821.810174] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-19)
[80822.327219] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[80822.332181] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[80822.332189] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[80822.332194] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[80822.332197] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[80822.332200] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[80822.332205] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[80822.332213] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[80824.097461] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[80824.098173] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1730272 usecs
[80824.098443] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[80824.110199] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11634 usecs
[80824.110274] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[80824.112241] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[80824.113188] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[216812.538175] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[216812.543151] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[216812.543154] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[216812.543156] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[216812.543157] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[216812.543159] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[216812.543161] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[216812.774025] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[216814.143072] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[216814.143195] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1567798 usecs
[216814.143327] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[216814.155215] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11646 usecs
[216814.155230] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[216814.157198] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[216814.158213] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[220354.341137] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[220354.351569] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[220354.351572] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[220354.351573] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[220354.351574] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[220354.351575] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[220354.351576] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[220354.351579] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[220355.707865] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[220355.708108] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1335327 usecs
[220355.708206] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[220355.720185] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11782 usecs
[220355.720263] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[220355.722198] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[220355.723267] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[282114.963418] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 12
[282125.957282] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 12
[282140.957175] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 12
[282174.044050] Bluetooth: Failed to start inquiry: status 12
[282187.498491] input: S530 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:512/0005:23A1:1234.0044/input/input82
[282187.500255] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.0044: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [S530] on a4:34:d9:5c:77:da
[388357.148985] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[388357.153957] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[388357.153960] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[388357.153962] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[388357.153963] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[388357.153964] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[388357.153966] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[388357.441745] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[388358.821058] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[388358.821918] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1634062 usecs
[388358.821988] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[388358.833978] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11728 usecs
[388358.833985] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[388358.836025] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[388358.837015] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[389303.062797] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[389303.082856] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[389303.082860] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[389303.082861] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[389303.082863] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[389303.082864] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[389303.082866] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[389303.082870] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[389304.444994] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[389304.445710] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1350905 usecs
[389304.445725] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[389304.457720] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11722 usecs
[389304.457757] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[389304.459716] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[389304.460711] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[394634.824993] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[394634.832055] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[394634.832059] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[394634.832061] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[394634.832062] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[394634.832064] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[394634.832066] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[394634.839290] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[394636.030016] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[394638.034280] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[394642.913375] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-19)
[394643.435905] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[394643.440923] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[394643.440926] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[394643.440928] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[394643.440930] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[394643.440931] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[394643.440933] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[394643.441129] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[394645.011504] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[394645.011979] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1539571 usecs
[394645.012062] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[394645.024024] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11674 usecs
[394645.024051] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[394645.026008] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[394645.026993] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[401548.548313] input: S530 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:23A1:1234.004B/input/input89
[401548.551003] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.004B: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [S530] on a4:34:d9:5c:77:da
[402430.543721] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[402440.106451] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
[402440.106866] Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported

lspci


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Imaging Unit (rev 01)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:14.3 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d32 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d46 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8621 (rev 01)



lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 049: ID 17ef:6084 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 050: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

edit ...

I thought adding linux-firmware-nonfree might solve the problem, but its still showing up as a keyboard and doesn't list any sound interface in the sound manager here's the updated dmesg.

```
[149359.111460] Broke affinity for irq 123 
[149359.111467] Broke affinity for irq 124 
[149359.111502] Broke affinity for irq 277 
[149359.111510] Broke affinity for irq 278 
[149359.111518] Broke affinity for irq 281
[149359.112616] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline 
[149359.128003] ACPI: Low-level resume complete 
[149359.128127] ACPI : EC: EC started 
[149359.128128] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory 
[149359.128987] Enabling non-boot CPUs ... 
[149359.147802] x86: Booting SMP configuration: 
[149359.147804] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2 
[149359.153878]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping 
[149359.154090] CPU1 is up 
[149359.171874] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1 
[149359.178449]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping 
[149359.178703] CPU2 is up 
[149359.207923] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3 
[149359.213957]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping 
[149359.214188] CPU3 is up 
[149359.223199] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3 
[149359.283623] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI 
[149359.283751] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 30.856 msecs 
[149359.304796] PM: early resume of devices complete after 20.957 msecs 
[149359.306242] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk 
[149359.306277] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149359.306901] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149359.368447] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 2 resume PLC timeout 
[149359.399916] rtc_cmos 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI 
[149359.454583] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149359.454829] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149359.600279] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd 
[149359.623762] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300) 
[149359.627597] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300) 
[149359.628601] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133 
[149359.643778] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep 
[149359.655082] mmc0: Problem setting current limit! 
[149359.707615] sdhci: Timeout waiting for Buffer Read Ready interrupt during tuning procedure, falling back to fixed sampling clock 
[149359.707619] mmc0: tuning execution failed 
[149359.707620] mmc0: ddr50 tuning failed 
[149359.785725] PM: resume of devices complete after 480.912 msecs 
[149359.786663] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014 
[149359.786731] PM: Finishing wakeup. 
[149359.786734] Restarting tasks ...  
[149359.787279] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment 
[149359.796214] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5 
[149359.796219] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled 
[149359.796221] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled 
[149359.796222] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled 
[149359.796224] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled 
[149359.796226] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014 
[149359.798735] done. 
[149359.798969] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi 
[149359.955548] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd 
[149360.148170] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=6084 
[149360.148178] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
[149360.148184] usb 1-7: Product: ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard 
[149360.148188] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Lenovo 
[149360.154537] input: Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:17EF:6084.004A/input/input88 
[149360.207969] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6084.004A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0 
[149360.219142] input: Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:17EF:6084.004B/input/input89 
[149360.271996] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6084.004B: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1 
[149360.743845] [drm] RC6 on 
[149360.775533] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep 
[149360.860123] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149360.941065] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149361.155968] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete 
[149361.156654] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1338249 usecs 
[149361.156733] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot 
[149361.168671] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11692 usecs 
[149361.168716] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc 
[149361.170666] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed 
[149361.171745] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16) 
[149364.196070] wlp1s0: authenticate with 06:27:22:f1:4b:58 
[149364.204100] wlp1s0: send auth to 06:27:22:f1:4b:58 (try 1/3) 
[149364.211986] wlp1s0: authenticated [149364.215673] wlp1s0: associate with 06:27:22:f1:4b:58 (try 1/3) 
[149364.219467] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 06:27:22:f1:4b:58 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=10) 
[149364.225621] wlp1s0: associated 
[149364.225663] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready 
[149910.848237] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 40 
[149910.848267] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment 
[149910.899156] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from 06:27:22:f1:4b:58 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) 
[149912.430987] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep 
[149912.585394] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done. 
[149912.598339] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem) 
[149912.599098] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done. 
[149912.601359] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done. 
[149912.602646] PM: Suspending system (mem) 
[149912.602667] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug) 
[149912.603629] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache 
[149912.603715] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk 
[149912.847394] PM: suspend of devices complete after 244.394 msecs 
[149912.867328] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 19.920 msecs 
[149912.869861] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI 
[149912.899101] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 31.764 msecs 
[149912.900482] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3 
[149912.919446] ACPI : EC: EC stopped 
[149912.919448] PM: Saving platform NVS memory 
[149912.919454] Disabling non-boot CPUs ... 
[149912.920195] Broke affinity for irq 281 
[149912.921326] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline 
[149912.932808] Broke affinity for irq 123 
[149912.932816] Broke affinity for irq 124 
[149912.932873] Broke affinity for irq 278 
[149912.932881] Broke affinity for irq 281 
[149912.934011] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline 
[149912.944492] Broke affinity for irq 1 
[149912.944503] Broke affinity for irq 8 
[149912.944511] Broke affinity for irq 9 
[149912.944521] Broke affinity for irq 14 
[149912.944531] Broke affinity for irq 16 
[149912.944540] Broke affinity for irq 17 
[149912.944550] Broke affinity for irq 18 
[149912.944558] Broke affinity for irq 19 
[149912.944569] Broke affinity for irq 34 
[149912.944579] Broke affinity for irq 47 
[149912.944592] Broke affinity for irq 122 
[149912.944600] Broke affinity for irq 123 
[149912.944608] Broke affinity for irq 124 
[149912.944649] Broke affinity for irq 277 
[149912.944659] Broke affinity for irq 278 
[149912.944668] Broke affinity for irq 281 
[149912.945770] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline 
[149912.961103] ACPI: Low-level resume complete 
[149912.961227] ACPI : EC: EC started 
[149912.961229] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory 
[149912.962091] Enabling non-boot CPUs ... 
[149912.981002] x86: Booting SMP configuration: 
[149912.981003] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2 
[149912.987071]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping 
[149912.987282] CPU1 is up 
[149913.005071] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1 
[149913.011489]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping 
[149913.011717] CPU2 is up 
[149913.041109] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3 
[149913.047240]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping 
[149913.047473] CPU3 is up 
[149913.056477] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3 
[149913.116828] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI 
[149913.116950] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 30.880 msecs 
[149913.146814] PM: early resume of devices complete after 29.777 msecs 
[149913.147992] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk 
[149913.210169] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 2 resume PLC timeout 
[149913.217082] rtc_cmos 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI 
[149913.464963] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)     
[149913.464997] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300) 
[149913.469386] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133 
[149913.471820] mmc0: Problem setting current limit! 
[149913.484958] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep 
[149913.493425] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd 
[149913.524962] sdhci: Timeout waiting for Buffer Read Ready interrupt during tuning procedure, falling back to fixed sampling clock 
[149913.524972] mmc0: tuning execution failed 
[149913.524973] mmc0: ddr50 tuning failed 
[149913.679208] PM: resume of devices complete after 532.374 msecs 
[149913.680146] PM: Finishing wakeup. [149913.680149] Restarting tasks ...  
[149913.680914] i915_bpo 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment 
[149913.692827] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014 
[149913.696657] done. 
[149913.698122] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5 
[149913.698125] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled 
[149913.698127] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled 
[149913.698128] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled 
[149913.698129] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled 
[149913.698131] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014 
[149913.698135] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi 
[149913.786090] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149913.786726] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149913.797154] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38) 
[149913.860877] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd 
[149913.932749] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149913.933018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149914.011241] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149914.050411] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149914.051037] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149914.053760] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=6084 
[149914.053764] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
[149914.053767] usb 1-7: Product: ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard 
[149914.053768] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Lenovo 
[149914.061488] input: Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:17EF:6084.004C/input/input90 
[149914.116961] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6084.004C: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0 
[149914.128196] input: Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:17EF:6084.004D/input/input91 
[149914.180987] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6084.004D: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Lenovo ideapad MIIX 700 USB keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1 
[149914.195449] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149914.195701] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled 
[149914.273577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149914.696854] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149914.736822] [drm] RC6 on 
[149914.785792] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready 
[149914.804745] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep 
[149915.800804] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout 
[149917.950769] wlp1s0: authenticate with 04:bd:88:c1:4b:30 
[149917.957881] wlp1s0: send auth to 04:bd:88:c1:4b:30 (try 1/3) 
[149917.967057] wlp1s0: authenticated 
[149917.968884] wlp1s0: associate with 04:bd:88:c1:4b:30 (try 1/3)\
[149917.991560] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 04:bd:88:c1:4b:30 (capab=0x1 status=0 aid=4) [149918.002170] wlp1s0: associated 
[149918.002217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready 
[149918.152395] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 36 (36 - 0) dBm as advertised by 04:bd:88:c1:4b:30 
[149920.680226] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 24 
[149920.680612] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-19) 
[149921.008975] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd 
[149921.194286] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b 
[149921.194300] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
[149921.198172] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014 
[149921.203199] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5 
[149921.203213] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled 
[149921.203220] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled 
[149921.203226] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled 
[149921.203232] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled 
[149921.203240] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014 
[149921.203253] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi 
[149922.907159] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete 
[149922.907168] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1670068 usecs 
[149922.907202] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot 
[149922.919163] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11707 usecs 
[149922.919168] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc 
[149922.921160] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed 
[149922.922156] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16) 
[150152.579299] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[150152.579310] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized 
[150152.757892] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.004E: unknown main item tag 0x0 
[150152.758460] input: S530 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:23A1:1234.004E/input/input92 
[150152.759857] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.004E: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [S530] on a4:34:d9:5c:77:da 
[150484.706712] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.004F: unknown main item tag 0x0 
[150484.706817] input: S530 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:23A1:1234.004F/input/input93 
[150484.707142] hid-generic 0005:23A1:1234.004F: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [S530] on a4:34:d9:5c:77:da
```